# incrementing a session variable inside a php function aswell as passing it to another page

Tags: php

I am currently creating a database driven multiple choice quiz however I have encountered a couple of problems, I have found that my session variable for score is not incrementing correctly and is not being passed correctly to the next page as shown below

any advice is welcome

Main Quiz Page

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
<title> World Cup Quiz  </title>
<style>
.main{margin-top:2cm};
.main{margin-left:10cm};
.main{margin-bottom:2cm};
.main{margin-right:10cm};

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div align = center >
<br />

<div class="main"  align =center>

<strong> World Cup Quiz</strong></div>
<?php


function Score($userScore)
{
    if(isset($_POST['correctAnswer'] ))

    {
        $_SESSION['score']=$userScore+1;

    }

    else
    {
     $_SESSION['score']=$_SESSION['score'];

     }




}


include ("dbConnect.php");

if (!isset($_SESSION['number']))
{
    $_SESSION['number']=1;
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['score']))

{
    $_SESSION['score']=0;

}


$questionNumber = $_SESSION['number'];
$userScore=$_SESSION['score'];
$number= rand(1,16);

//search database for generated number and match ID
$dbQuery= "SELECT * FROM `questions 1.0` WHERE  `ID` =$number";
$dbResult=mysql_query($dbQuery);

echo "Question:".$questionNumber."/5<br>";

//Assign variables to each attribute

while ($dbRow=mysql_fetch_array($dbResult))

{
 if ($_SESSION['number']>5)

    {
        header("Location: results.php");
        $_SESSION['number']=1;
        break;


    }

   $theID=$dbRow["ID"];
   $theQuestion=$dbRow["Question"];
   $theAnswer1=$dbRow["Correct Answer"];
   $theAnswer2=$dbRow["Wrong Answer 1"];
   $theAnswer3=$dbRow["Wrong Answer 2"];
   $theAnswer4=$dbRow["Wrong Answer 3"];
   $_SESSION['number']=$questionNumber+1;


}

  //Print Questions and Answers


    echo '<strong>'."$theQuestion".'</strong><br>';

   ?> <form name="correctAnswer" form method="post" action="quiz.php" onSubmit="Score(<?$userScore?>)"> 
   <table border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                          <?php
                           echo "$theAnswer1";?></td><td> <input type="radio" id="correct_answer" name="correctAnswer"></td>
                    </tr>
                       <tr>
                       <td>
                      <?php
                       echo "$theAnswer2"; ?></td><td> <input type="radio" id="wrong_answer1" name="wrongAnswer1"> </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                       <td>
                       <?php
                       echo "$theAnswer3"; ?> </td><td><input type="radio" id="wrong_answer2" name="wrongAnswer2"> </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                       <td>
                       <?php
                       echo "$theAnswer4"; ?></td><td><input type="radio" id="wrong_answer3" name="wrongAnswer3"> </td>
                       </tr>
                       <input type="hidden" name="score" value="userScore">
                       <tr>
                       <td>
                       <input type="submit" value="Submit Answer"></td>
                       </tr>
             </tbody>
        </table>

   </form>


</div>
</body>
```

Results Page

```
<html>

<head>

<title> Result</title>
<style>
.main{margin-top:2cm};
.main{margin-left:10cm};
.main{margin-bottom:2cm};
.main{margin-right:10cm};

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div align =center class="main">
    <?php

    $score=$_SESSION['score'];

    echo "Congratulations you scored $score /5<br>"

    ?>

    <form action="menu.php">

    <input type="submit" value="Return to Main Menu">
    </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope you can help

Comment: Anybody have any idea?

Comment: Can you tell me how do you run function Score($userScore) ?

Comment: When the user selects the submit button from the form

Comment: No. [onSummit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp) is a event witch triggers JavaScript function. This function is never called in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't run `Score()` function.
Add this under include line.

```
include ("dbConnect.php");
if( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] )
{
    Score( $_POST[ 'userScore' ] );
}
```